# Fitting a 2D-function to a 2D dataset with errors in python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I have a 2D np.array as experimental data, so something with a shape like (50,50), corresponding to the pixel of my cam. I have a second np.array of the same shape for errors on each point. So my error isn't just sqrt(n). I would like to use those errors for a fit, so using sum( (experimental - function)^2 / (error of the pixel)^2 ).

Up to now, to handle 2D I just flatten my errorfunction as input for leastsq. This works perfectly. So I have fit parameters taking account of the errors. But there is one Problem: How do I tell leastsq it has also to use them to calculate the errors on my fitparameters?
I looked at curve_fit, but it seems absolutly not designed for my case. It seems to me it needs a function which you can give an x as an input. But with my convolution I can't simply convert a x-value in a y-value.

so is there a way to do this with leastsq, with curve_fit or an other function?

Here is the script without taking care of the error of the fitparameters:

```
#img is my experimental data, errimg the array with the errors.
#My fitfunction is a convolution of a bivariate_normal with a circular
#box-function given by a function i called ellipsenmatrix.

tx = np.arange(-100,100,1.)    
ty = np.arange(-100,100,1.)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(tx, ty)

circ= lambda x: ellipsenmatrix([24.,24.,x],shape=img.shape,kreis='on')

def fitfunc(v):
    conv= ndimage.convolve( circ(v[4]), mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], 0) )
    conv/=np.sum(conv)
    return conv

errfunc = lambda v: ( (fitfunc(v) - img) /errimg ).flatten()
vinit=[2.5,2.5,0,0,27.5]
vend, kovmtx, einstell, mesg, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, vinit, full_output=True)

print vend
```

Comment: For those wondering what happend about the runtime-error and the nans: they weren't related to the fitting problem, just an error in the input.

Comment: Okay, I just worked my way through the curve_fit function to see how she calculates the error.
For the fitparameters them self she does exactly the same then above: she takes [(fitfunction - experimental ydata) / error] for the error she passes through to leastsq.
For the error she takes the covariance-array given by leastsq and multiplies it with [chi**2 / (ndf - number of parameters)], or to be more precise with (errorfunction**2).sum() / (len(ydata)-len(fitparam))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short function I wrote inspired of what curve_fit does. You can give her a 2D-array as input for the errorfunction but don't have to. The errorfunction is (fitfunc(v) - img) /errimg, where errimg is a matrix of the same shape than img full of errors on each datapoint. Output is the same than for leastsq but the covariance-matrix is corrected.

```
def leastsqplus(func, x0, args=(), Dfun=None, full_output=0, col_deriv=0,ftol=1.49012e-8, xtol=1.49012e-8, gtol=0.0, maxfev=0, epsfcn=0.0, factor=100, diag=None):
    func=func.flatten()
    vend, kovmtx, einstell, mesg, success = optimize.leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    X2 = np.sum( func(vend)**2 )
    ndf = ( len(func(vend)) - len(vend) )
    X2ndf= X2 / ndf
    kovmtx *= X2ndf
    return vend, kovmtx, einstell, mesg, success
```